# What does the comma mean in typescript

Tags: typescript

What does the `,` mean? Is it the same as `|` which is it can be either the first type or any?

```
CustomFieldValue<Sometype, any>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the list of type parameters - pretty similar to an argument list. Each type parameter is separated by a comma. For example, with

```
type CustomFieldValue<K, V> = Map<K, V>;
type mapOfStringsByNumbers = CustomFieldValue<number, string>
```

The first type parameter `number` corresponds to K, and the second type parameter `string` corresponds to V, so the result is the type of a Map whose keys are numbers and values are strings.

Your

```
CustomFieldValue<Sometype, any>
```

is passing two type parameters to `CustomFieldValue`: `Sometype` and `any`. It's not a union.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `CustomFieldValue` has two generic types one is `SomeType` and the other is `any`. A `,` is simply a generic type separator. You can learn more about Typescript Generics [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes).

An example of a class CustomFieldValue with two generic fields could be:

```
public class CustomFieldValue<T, K> {
    field1: T;
    field2: K;
}
```

Then, when you want to use it:

```
const myValue = new CustomFieldValue<SomeType, any>();
// myValue.field1 is of type SomeType
// myValue.field2 is of type any
```

A `|` is used to define union types, as described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types)